# Any limit on max size of item in Reliable Queue and Reliable Dictionary?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Does service fabric reliable queue and reliable dictionary has limit on max size of  each added item in queue or dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a hard limit, but a performance consideration, from the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections-guidelines):

> Consider keeping your items (for example, TKey + TValue for Reliable
>   Dictionary) below 80 KBytes: smaller the better. This reduces the
>   amount of Large Object Heap usage as well as disk and network IO
>   requirements.

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36752442/5946937) answer by one of the SF team members, which explains some additional capacity limits.